# Webpage with Javascript forwarding rendering/simulating in Java

Tags: javascript, java, web-crawler, htmlunit, doi

There is a web service that provides a link to a given DOI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier), which can be used to access the PDF of the associated document. The link has the following structure, see: https://libkey.io/libraries/1420/articles/362897792/full-text-file?utm_source=api_50

If you access the link, you will be redirected to the PDF document. This works fine if I want to access the document with the browser. But if I want to download the PDF document programmatically or via Java, I need the direct link to the PDF.

My question: How can I get direct access to the PDF. Is there a library that can simulate the browser in Java? Do you know other ways to get to the PDF.

If my problem is not understandable enough, ask me specific questions!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes there are libraries. But how to get to the file is impossible to say. You need to have auth to get through to the page in the first place

Comment: Ok, since I am on the intranet, the PDF appears directly. In your case you have to authenticate yourself first. That was my mistake. I should have mentioned that. 
Just assume that a PDF appears.